# What is the preferred method for generating strong passwords using bash?

Tags: bash, passwords

I just call the following in a function, where $1 is the character length of the output:

```
    export LANG=C; cat /dev/random | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=' | fold -w $1 | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I use tools like [pwgen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen) or [apg](http://linux.die.net/man/1/apg). Or even something like

```
uuid | base64
```